# custom woocommerce checkout form fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i have the following function adding a checkbox to the woocommerce checkout form:

```
woocommerce_form_field( 'email_signup', array(
    'type'          => 'checkbox',
    'class'         => array('input-checkbox'),
    'label'         => __('Newsletter Signup?'),
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'email_signup' ));
```

I would like to make the checkbox selected by default. Is there a way of doing it through woocommerce form_field options? Or will i need to use javascript?

Answer (score 5):

Adding **'default' => 1** should do the trick

```
woocommerce_form_field( 'email_signup', array(
'type'          => 'checkbox',
'class'         => array('input-checkbox'),
'label'         => __('Newsletter Signup?'),
'checked'       => 'checked',
'default'       => 1,
), $checkout->get_value( 'email_signup' ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
woocommerce_form_field( 'email_signup', array(
'type'          => 'checkbox',
'class'         => array('input-checkbox'),
'label'         => __('Newsletter Signup?'),
'checked'       => 'checked',
), $checkout->get_value( 'email_signup' ));
```

Answer (score 0):

By including:

```
'checked'       => 'checked',
'default'       => 1,
```

in array, would do the trick.. Voila!

Answer (score -1):

you can certainly do that, with [this plugin](http://www.trottyzone.com/product/woocommerce-checkout-manager/)

Also you can actually insert your very own two options for checkbox. "Yes" or "No" etc

Comment: The link on which this answer relies does not work anymore.